# SQL Server: Best way to automatically stream updates to a summary table based on changes from another table

Tags: sql-server

I am currently working in a SQL server database where I have a table `User` that has a schema like so:

| username | category |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | gaming |
| user2 | gaming |
| user3 | sports |

My summary table `UserCategoryCount` is a simple `groupby` statement for how many users belong to each category and looks like this:

| category | numUsers |
| --- | --- |
| gaming | 2 |
| sports | 1 |

New entries are constantly being uploaded to the `User`, and I want to be able to stream updates in the `User` table to the `UserCategoryCount` summary table. I am aware that I can create a simple VIEW statement that performs a `groupby` on the `User` table, but I would like `UserCategoryCount` to be its own table that automatically changes based on new users being uploaded to the `User` table.

My first thought was to create a trigger that will detect when the `User` table has been updated. So far, the most simple but cheesy solution I can think of is creating a trigger that simply deletes and refreshes `UserCategoryCount`:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_Add_User
ON User
AS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM UserCategoryCount
INSERT INTO UserCategoryCount (category, numUsers)
SELECT Category, Count(Category) as numUsers
FROM User GROUP BY Category
END
GO
```

But this seems like a really hacky way of updating the `UserCategoryCount` table. Any help on how to improve this update statement so that I don't have to completely overwrite the table every time a new user or batch of users has been inserted would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is a really "hacky" way. It can be improved and made more efficient by using the virtual inserted and deleted tables available to triggers. But why bother? Explain why you discarded the idea of a view. Logically a view is the typical approach. And I have trouble believing that rows are constantly added to the user table. This sounds like premature optimization.

Comment: I'm not sure why the view doesn't work for you - it's the logical approach, trying to maintain a summary in a separate table is just introducing unecessary duplication and overhead. What problem are you solving with the separate table?

Comment: @Stu I'm trying to simulate an ETL job where I am transforming the input data of the `User` table and streaming it to a separate table. I guess it can be thought of less as a summary table and more a transformed table that should, in-practice exist in a separate database or datalake? Also @SMor Yes, I am trying to work with the virtual inserted tables available through triggers, since that seems like a way that I can actually transform the output into a separate table.

Comment: Does the target table need to be updated in real time? ETL process typically don't occur in real-time but either overnight or in batches; would a scheduled Job not be a better approach?

Comment: It does need to be performed in real time. Sorry for my misuse of terminology there. It's more of a streaming job than an ETL job.

Comment: Have a look at [Change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2):

For a start, your trigger is seriously flawed: it does not use the `inserted` or `deleted` tables and instead recalculates the whole thing every time, this is going to be very bad for performance. It also does not specify whether it is for inserts, updates or deletes.

**A much better solution is to use an indexed view.** This is like a regular view, except that the server maintains the actual data on disk, and updates it in real-time whenever there are changes to the underlying tables.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.UserCategoryCount
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    u.Category,
    COUNT_BIG(*) AS numUsers
FROM dbo.User u
GROUP BY u.Category;

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_UserCategoryCount ON dbo.UserCategoryCount (Category);
```

**There are some restrictions on indexed views,** among them:

- They must be schema-bound, and therefore underlying columns cannot be changed
- All tables must be two-part, schema and table
- Only joins allowed are `INNER` or `CROSS`, no `LEFT/RIGHT/FULL/APPLY` or derived tables, CTEs or subqueries.
- If there is a `GROUP BY`, you *must* add `COUNT_BIG`, and the only other aggregate allowed is `SUM`